# Handling events triggered by dynamically created DataGrids

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, datagrid, event-handling

When a user presses the `AddIndex` button a new `TabPage` is created containing a new `DataGrid`. This dynamically created `DataGrid` contains all values of the selected `TreeView Node BindingSource`. All is fine this far, but...

I must be able to handle the event of a user changing a cell value in my dynamically created `DataGrid`. But I don't know how to access the cell change event of a dynamically created grid?

This code execute when a user presses the `AddIndex` button:

```
private void addIndexTabButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (myTreeView.SelectedNode == null) return;

    myNode selectedNode = (myNode)myTreeView.SelectedNode.Tag;

    TabPage page = new TabPage(selectedNode.Name);

    DataGrid grid = new DataGrid();
    grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    grid.DataSource = selectedNode.Index;

    page.Controls.Add(grid);
    myTabControl.Controls.Add(page);
}

private class myNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BindingSource Index { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Forms [`DataGrid` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) has been superseded by [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx), which has a `CellValueChanged` event. If it's not an absolute requirement that you must use `DataGrid`, I'd consider using `DataGridView` instead.

You can give it a handler like so:

```
DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();

grid.CellValueChanged += Grid_CellValueChanged;
```

The handler looks like this:

```
private static void Grid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;

    //  Do stuff
}
```